# Group unique dates, and create a new column based on calculation pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have just moved from R to Python and have an issue regarding groupby. I have a dataframe with three features as shown below:

```
date    Scaled  Name
3   2018-10-01 02:00:00 14.57   19245
4   2018-10-01 02:00:00 11.90   7245
5   2018-10-01 02:00:00 15.84   25245
6   2018-10-01 03:00:00 16.98   25245
7   2018-10-01 03:00:00 11.40   7245
8   2018-10-01 03:00:00 16.95   19245
9   2018-10-01 04:00:00 17.78   25245
10  2018-10-01 04:00:00 12.06   7245
11  2018-10-01 04:00:00 18.19   19245
12  2018-10-01 05:00:00 19.63   25245
```

I have around 80 unique names in the dataset and hence duplicate dates. I would like to create a new column in the data set which is a percentage unique to each Name showing the proportion of hours for that particular Name compared to the total range of hours in the dataset. I can easily make this calculation, but I am struggling with generating the new column. The calculation would be something like this

```
hours = ((df['date'].max(axis=0) - df['date'].min(axis=0)).total_seconds())/3600

df['percentage'] = df['Name'].value_counts()/ hours
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close, only add [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['percentage'] = df['Name'].map(df['Name'].value_counts())/ hours
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['percentage'] = df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size')/ hours
```

---

```
print (df)
                 date  Scaled   Name  percentage
0 2018-10-01 02:00:00   14.57  19245    1.000000
1 2018-10-01 02:00:00   11.90   7245    1.000000
2 2018-10-01 02:00:00   15.84  25245    1.333333
3 2018-10-01 03:00:00   16.98  25245    1.333333
4 2018-10-01 03:00:00   11.40   7245    1.000000
5 2018-10-01 03:00:00   16.95  19245    1.000000
6 2018-10-01 04:00:00   17.78  25245    1.333333
7 2018-10-01 04:00:00   12.06   7245    1.000000
8 2018-10-01 04:00:00   18.19  19245    1.000000
9 2018-10-01 05:00:00   19.63  25245    1.333333
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Do you mind explaining the difference between using the groupby function and map as you did there?

Comment: Sorry just seen your links in the answer, I will look at those.

Comment: `df['percentage'] = df['Name'].map(df['Name'].value_counts()/hours)` faster:)